# Why won't my database work?

Tags: python, django

I added new columns in my `models.py` file, saved my code, then in `Terminal` I ran `sudo python manage.py makemigrations music` followed by `sudo python manage.py migrate`.  Upon running `sudo python manage.py migrate`, I get an error in `Terminal` saying:

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>The Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'index.css' %}">
</head>

<body>


    <form class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" method="POST" name="formHandler">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="userNameMovement">
            <label for="usr">Email:</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required="required">
        </div>

        <div class="passwordMovement">
            <label for="usr">Username:</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="Username" required="required">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my `models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=4)
    userName = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=4)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email + " - " + self.userName

class UI(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here's my `views.py` file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Person

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        userName = request.POST.get('userName')
        if email and userName:
            user = Person.objects.create(email=email, username=userName)
            user.save()
    return render(request, 'music/index.html')

def detail(request, user_id): # Testing out page 2
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Page # (testing this out) " + str(user_id) + "</h2>")
```

Comment: You should certainly not be running your migrations as `sudo`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I tried running it without sudo, still doesn't work.  I can't `.save()` any Person object in Terminal without getting an error

Comment: In your other migrations files, do you see any migration with the email field?

Answer (score 0):

The terminal output you post is no error. It just tells you what happened in your database.

Everything should be fine, unless there are other error messages..

Comment: Yes but after I created a Person object and giving a username, email, and password and then `object.save()` and then `Person.objects.all()`, I get nothing

Comment: When I do `object.save()`, I get an error that says `OperationalError: table music_person has no column named email
`

Comment: Can you manually check your database? Check if the table music_person exists and has column named email. Check your settings.py if not. Can be a misconfigured database problem.

Comment: It's not there.  I'm checking in /admin.  In fact, when I click on the Person (to check what's in my database) link in my /admin page it throws me `OperationalError at /admin/music/person/`

Comment: try removing the email line from your model. Run again makemigrations and migrate and see if you can add a person object without the email field first.

Comment: Also, your default value on all three charfields in an integer (4). Try changing that to a string (f.ex. "four")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146891/discussion-between-bojack-and-debaze).